# install svn server on windows

Tags: windows, svn

I want to install a SVN server on a Windows 7 64 bit machine (just for me).

I used Slik SVN and set up a service with:

```
sc create svnserver binpath= "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r H:\svn\repository" displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

This is listed in the list of services, but can not be started:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc create svnserver binpath= "C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\s
vnserve.exe --service -r H:\svn\repository" displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tc
pip start= auto
[SC] CreateService ERFOLG

C:\Windows\system32>net start svnserver
Der Dienst reagiert auf die Kontrollfunktion nicht.
```

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: You can access repositories over file:/// protocol without even installing a server. It makes sense to stick to this method if you are a lone developer :)

Comment: Are you sure the binpath takes the arguments, too?  To answer my own question: I think you can.  But then the spaces in the pathname are not escaped.  Try using the alternate name or a symlink/junction without spaces in the pathname.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but if you're on windows, you may want to try using Visual SVN Server (http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) -- it is very easy to get up and running, and it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that you want to install a SVN server just for yourself, i.e. you are going to be the only user of the system. So what's the purpose of installing a SVN *server* in this case?

*Did you decide to setup svnserve because you consider this as the easiest way to make your repositories accessible for clients?* If you did, then you've missed the easier way to access your repositories:

- *You can use direct repository access (on local disk).*
  I.e. you can access a repository with the URL: `file:///C:\Repositories\MyProject1` or `file:///C:\Repositories\MyProject1\trunk\repo-folder`.
- If you need to create a clean repository you may use a command-line:

  `svnadmin create C:\Repositories\MyProject1`

You don't need a svnserve or Apache HTTP Server for that.

I can agree that Subversion bundles like VisualSVN Server make it much easier to maintain your repositories and understand why one installs it on a laptop for personal use and even uses HTTPS access locally. However I completely don't understand why would anyone want to setup a personal svnserve-based SVN server on Windows! There is no real use case for that, IMHO. Better consider a dedicated SVN package or use direct `file://` access.

Answer (score 5):

From [Svnserve Based Server](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html) page of TortoseSVN docs, "Run svnserve as a Service" chapter. Your **path have space** in name

> If any of the paths include spaces, you have to use (escaped) quotes
>   around the path, like this:

```
sc create svnserve binpath= "
    \"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe\"
    --service --root c:\repos" displayname= "Subversion"
    depend= tcpip start= auto
```